Connecting two Edifiers to a single output
Alright so, I have some R1280DBs for now but I want to buy some R2750DB, can i by any chance connect the two together using an Y splitter cable to my PC? I dont really want to get rid of the R1280's so please help if you can!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Details missing on WHAT this thing is about.

Yes you can. Do note that both speakers will be stereo, you don't get surround this way. Its just the same sound coming from both speakers, and the volume may be a bit lower too, but its possible nevertheless.
I actually did this for my 5.1 sub with 7.1 speakers. I connected 2 sets of speakers to front left and front right to get fuller sound.
Basically, I had a Creative Gigaworks s750 7.1 speakerset, and after a powercut outside, a surge blew up my subwoofer. I bought a Logitech Z906 speakerset but its only 5.1 surround. I decided to keep my 7 small speakers in place and just replace the sub and control unit. front left and side left both were wired to front left, and the same for right and this works great.
With audio, its all a low voltage analog signal, and as such you can split the signal into multiple cables. Just keep in mind as you split the cable, the voltage for both sides cuts in half, so it is like you half the volume. Most speakers are amplified anyway, so although the speakers now can go less high in volume, the fact that there are now 2 cancels that out.
One thing you will have to pay close attention to: the lenght of the cables should be the same everywhere after the split. So if you split the cable and then one cable is like 0.5m and the other is 2m, it will take longer for the sound to reach the other speaker, and you will hear weird artifacts as sound cancels out in your room.
It doesn't have to be perfect, but the closer the better.

Thanks man! I honestly dont want surround sound it's just the fact that i cant get rid of my R1280DBs cause they have a place in my heart . Plus I think that it will just be louder right?
